What does this mean: "AdaBoost can continuously improve the margin distribution of all training samples"?
I am reading a machine learning book with the following paragraph:

A theoretical analysis [215] suggests that
AdaBoost can continuously improve the margin distribution of all training
samples, which may prevent AdaBoost from overfitting when more and
more base models are added to the ensemble even after the training error
has reached 0.

What does this mean: "AdaBoost can continuously improve the margin distribution of all training samples"?
